# Is it possible to switch the primary key of a synchronized data extension while using MCC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is it possible to switch the primary key of a synchronized data extension from Salesforce Id to Email Address for Contact object in Salesforce Marketing Cloud while using the Marketing Cloud connect?

Just a heads-up: The Salesforce ID (Id) is presently related to the Subscriber Key in certain data extensions utilized for manual sends.

And is it a best practice to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this, and it will for sure not be best practice. The Synced DEs are using the primary key in accordance with the data model in Sales Cloud. This is normally the native record ID there. I can't see why you would like to change this directly in the synchronised DE.

You always have the option of querying these DEs and pushing the output of the query to a custom data extension with the primary key of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.

We can certainly to retrieve information from the sync Data Extensions. 
However, my current approach involves filters with various criteria to obtain the desired output. But, the filtered Data Extension is automatically adopting the primary key from the synchronized data extension. 

I will continue to think of a work around, as you mentioned that it is not a good practice to make the switch.

Comment: @user147129 And that's why you should rather create a denormalised data extension (using SQL) containing data from multiple synced DEs, and use this as a basis for your filtering.